# Specify .ist-File for latexmk in TextMate

Tags: indexing, latexmk, textmate

So I'm using latexmk.pl to compile my TextMate LaTeX Project and it's running quite nice. The only thing I'm missing, is, that i want to specify an individual style file for the `makeindex` command, i.e. latexmk.pl when `latexmk` decides to run makeindex, it should add something like

```
makeindex -s mystyle.ist
```

I won't mind setting the .ist file to my $TM_LATEX_MASTERs name, but it would also be nice to have a seperate style file.

I haven't found anything to define such an option for latexmk that is called from TextMate. Do you have any ideas?

PS: I'm using XeTeX to compile, but i think that might only be of minor interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running a TeX Live 2010 or 2011, or MiKTeX 2.9, you can profit from the **imakeidx** package: just change `\usepackage{makeidx}` to

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
```

and `\makeindex` to

```
\makeindex[options=-s mystyle]
```

Then MakeIndex (the program) will be called automatically from within the LaTeX run, with the specified style (doesn't work with the **article** class and, presently, **memoir**).

Comment: That's a neat Hint. Though the index just does not show up, but that may also be due to an error in my style-definitions, i'll check that tomorrow. I'm using the Koma-Classes (scrbook actually), so it seems to work (despite the mentioned error). Many thanks.

Comment: So thanks, it really works, now i have to understand more about the style file itself. I think this solution is great.

Comment: @Ronny Well, I'm one of the authors. :)

Comment: I red your manual last night, though i didn't get the link to your username. Thanks for that package, it's e great idea.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to redefine the command latexmk uses to run makeindex.  Make a file latexmkrc in the directory containing your document, and include in it the following line

```
$makeindex  = 'makeindex -s mystyle.ist %O -o %D %S';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i think specifying it inside the .tex document as mentioned directly below is a little bit nicer, though i might try your idea, just to learn configuring latexmkrc.

Comment: So i reset my repository and tried your solution, too. It works, and it would also work on older distributions compared to the solution of egreg, so maybe for some of the readers that might be nice. I prefer the solution using imakeidx, because it's more flexible. I can change the style in my .tex-Files, which is even better for me than the starting point of this thread. Thanks again.

Comment: @john-collins When you say a `latexmkrc` file, Do you mean a `.latexmkrc` file or the dot does not matter?

Answer (score 0):

You could try entering the contents of your .ist into your .tex file using `\begin(filecontents)` as in this example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
delim_0 "\\quad "
delim_1 "\\quad "
delim_2 "\\quad "
delim_n ", "
\end{filecontents}
```

(Note the file extension needs to be .mst: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117205/128965 for an explanation.)