# Differences between .ist and .mst files in the index personalization

Tags: indexing

Are there some differences between `.ist` and `.mst` files in the index personalization? 
For example if I put an `.ist` file in the project folder and if I execute MakeIndex with this option:

```
makeindex -s istfilename
```

I have the personalization of the index, but also if I put an `.mst` file into the project folder I have that personalization but this time, without the previous options for MakeIndex, is there just this difference?

Comment: The difference is that if MakeIndex spots a `.mst` file in the current directory, it uses that as if you passed a `-s` option.

Comment: @egreg so is the same thing use a `.mst` file and don't pass the `-s` option at MakeIndex and use a `.ist` file and pass the `-s` option; have I understand well?

Comment: Yes, you did. My impression is that you've been asking several XY questions.

Answer (score 13):

When executing

```
makeindex filename
```

if a file named exactly `filename.mst` is present in the current directory, MakeIndex will use it as if the option `-s filename.mst` had been present in the command line.

So, when a unique index is being prepared, it may be convenient to have such a `.mst` file instead of naming it with the `.ist` extension and passing the `-s` option.

This however has a limited usefulness when more than one index is being prepared and a particular style file is desired. So my advice is to use `.ist` as the extension for the personal style file `mystyle.ist` and passing the `-s mystyle` option to the call of MakeIndex.